# Raspberry hosting bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I tried to run my bot on raspberry, it does not work unless I don't put the token, on windows I can read a file called token.txt, then put "client.run(token)" but on the raspberry it gives me an error: error 4004 authentication failed

```py
import discord
import os
import random
from random import choice
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
client.remove_command("help")

f = open("token.txt", "r")
token = f.read()


@client.command()
async def someone(ctx):
    try:
        await ctx.send(choice(tuple(member.mention for member in ctx.guild.members if not member.bot and member != ctx.author and member.status == discord.Status.online)))
    except IndexError:
        await ctx.send("You are the only human member on it!")

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

client.run(token)
```

This is the error it gives:
discord.errors.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 4004 (private use), reason = Authentication failed.

Comment: Check where the token.txt file is located, check if correct path is being read, and check if tocken inside the file is what you expect it to be.

Comment: @MatJ the file is located in the same directory as the bot

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the token.txt was not read correctly.
solved changing

```py
client.run(token)
```

in

```py
client.run(token.strip())
```